# Parsing Openweather API Python

Tags: python, json, openweathermap

Okay, I've got a bit of a situation and I've hit a road block in understanding how to pull values out of JSON returned from an API. I have the following code:

```
import requests
import json

weather_results = []
key = 'somekey'
cities = ['sometown']

def weather_get(apikey, city):
    r = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={},canada&APPID={}'.format(city, apikey))
    return(r.text)
```

This will return a long string of JSON formatted like so:

```
[u'{"coord":{"lon":-73.59,"lat":45.51},"weather":[{"id":521,"main":"Rain","description":"shower rain","icon":"09d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":277.5,"pressure":1022,"humidity":55,"temp_min":277.15,"temp_max":278.15},"visibility":24140,"wind":{"speed":3.1,"deg":300},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1490810400,"sys":{"type":1,"id":3829,"message":0.0973,"country":"CA","sunrise":1490783901,"sunset":1490829598},"id":6077243,"name":"Montreal","cod":200}']
```

Now, if I write a functon like so:

```
def get_temp_min(arg):
for items in arg:
    data = json.loads(items)
    for key, value in data['main'].items():
        if key=='temp_min':
            return(value)
```

It will return back the following value, but if I try:

```
def get_weather_description(arg):
for items in arg:
    data = json.loads(items)
    for key, value in data['weather'].items():
      if key=='description':
          return(value)
```

I'm not getting back the type of response that I'd want. I've tried something like this, to see if I could get deeper into the JSON:

```
def get_weather_description(arg):
for items in arg:
    data = json.loads(items)
    for key, value in data.items():
        if key=='weather':
            data2= value
            for items in data2:
                data3 = items
```

But I feel like I'm not on the right track at the moment, if anyone could offer some advice, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Suggestion is if a response is a JSON object then instead of using `r.text` try `r.json()` and iterate through the values.

Comment: @kiran.koduru Okay, I'm going to go give that a shot.

Comment: There is no `for key, value in something` in python. Python's `for` works as forEach function in other languages.

Comment: @EminMastizada There is definitely a `for key, val in dictionary_object.items()` in python

Comment: @kiran.koduru, because items() turns dict object into a list of tuples with two elements, [0] as key and [1] as value. It is kind of hack like `key, value = ('key', 'value')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've done a couple of things to make this better, I've implemented to @kiran.kodur's suggestion of

```
def weather_get(apikey, city):
r = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={},canada&APPID={}'.format(city, apikey))
return(r.json())
```

The 'return(r.json())' has made the code cleaner:

```
def get_temp(arg):
for items in arg:
    for key, value in items['main'].items():
        if key=='temp':
            return(value)
def get_pressure(arg):
    for items in arg:
        for key, value in items['main'].items():
            if key=='pressure':
                return(value)
def get_temp_min(arg):
    for items in arg:
        for key, value in items['main'].items():
            if key=='temp_min':
                return(value)
```

It also turns out that I need to modify:

```
for key, value in data.items()
```

To:

```
for key, value in items['weather'][0].items():
```

I was able to return back what I needed with this.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small function to get the needed information out of the weather data provided by openweatherdata.

```
def get_value_from_dictionary(dic, keys):
    if type(dic)is dict: #check if dic is a dictionary
        if len(keys)==1:
            value=dic.get(keys[0])
        else:
            dic=dic.get(keys[0])
            value=get_value_from_dictionary(dic,keys[1:])
    elif type(dic)is type(None): #if dic is None
        value=None
    elseif type(dic) is list: #if dic is a list
        dic=dic[keys[0]]
        value=get_value_from_dictionary(dic,keys[1:])
    return value
```

This function goes iterativly through a given dictionary until it finds your final key of interest.

This may be called by this (using ParanoidsPenguin definition):

```
weather = weather_get({'yourapikey'}, {'yourcity'})
current_weather_description = get_value_from_dictionary(weather,["weather",0,"description"])
current_snow_1h=get_value_from_dictionary(x,["snow", "1h"])
```